# Wildcard search in WP Query

Tags: wp-query, search

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'custom-text-field',
        'value' => '%rocket%',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

My goal being that the query will search through all the text of the `custom-text-field` and return any post where `rocket` is found. However it isn't working (I either get all the posts or no results). Is this possible directly in the `WP_Query` or do I need to use `$wpdb` to construct something first?

Answer (score 2):

[`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) will add the `%` wildcard operators for a `LIKE` query. Just remove those. As is your query looks like `LIKE '%\\%rocket\\%%` which is not what you want. Try

```
var_dump($query->request);
```

And you can see that for yourself.